# Insert SQL Server row into specific position in formatted table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, corresponding-records, delete-record

I'm new at creating database and currently trying to accomplish something that is really necessary for me.

Lets say I have a Database "Customer" with 300 rows all with a unique identifier called `Id_`.

```
Id_ | Customer | Postal | Country |
200 | Mica Sa. | 99582 | USA
201 | Shum Jr. | 10258 | USA
202 | Carl Ro. | 45697 | USA
203 | Brad Mi. | 24761 | USA
```

If i delete a row number 202 using:

```
DELETE FROM Customer
WHERE Id_ = 202;
```

I Get:

```
Id_ | Customer | Postal | Country |
200 | Mica Sa. | 99582 | USA
201 | Shum Jr. | 10258 | USA
203 | Brad Mi. | 24761 | USA
```

But when I try to insert a row using:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Id_, Customer, Postal, Country)
VALUES (202, 'Peter R.', 08574, 'USA');
```

I get the row randomly inserted in the database, so my question is how do I insert this row exactly after `201(Id_)` and before `203(Id_)`?

Comment: Do you have Id as primary key? And are you refering to position of a row?

Comment: Can't you just use a `ORDER BY Id_`? Data rarely every is neatly ordered in a database anyway...

Comment: i still don't get the question, are you mean you cannot insert 202 or the row position is not ascending (or descending) ? what `data type` of  `id_` column ?

Comment: Tables don't *have* an order. The only way to guarantee the order in which rows are retrieved is to specify an `ORDER BY` clause on the query that produces the output.

Comment: Okay, then I guess is impossible, so my next question is: Is it possible to make the SQl show the rows in certain order when I right click a DB table and select edit all rows? In this case it will be shown organized by Id_ value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you clear some things up:

- ID field seems to be int and not  unique identifier
- Insert statements are not made randomly in the DB, they go to the last record. E.G if you have 201,203 and you insert 202 it will go after 203.
- The way you select the records (and thus they fetched and displayed) is another thing. You may run a query that return 202 before 203 but this doesn't mean that this is the way that are stored in the DB
- If ID are actually of type int I recon you make them auto incremental

  Select * from Customer Order by Id_ Desc

Comment: Where the rows end up depends on the clustered index. In a heap, or if the clustered index is on a strictly increasing column value, they go at the end, but otherwise they go where the clustered index dictates that they go. Of course, the fact that the clustered index is organized in a certain manner has no effect on the order in which rows are (guranteed to be) retrieved.

Comment: The truth is I wasn't aware of that, just cause 99% of the times I use auto inc as index they end up in the end...

Comment: Okay, then I guess is impossible, so my next question is: Is it possible to make the SQl show the rows in certain order when I right click a DB table and select edit all rows? In this case it will be shown organized by Id_ value.

Comment: And I say that the data is inserted randomly, because I have more than  30,000 rows and I can't see to find the row I am looking form when I use the edit all rows options.